CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE env variable doesn't exist
I've a GitLab CI and try to create a rule based on CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE predefined variable. When I print all env variable with env keyword, CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE doesn't exist. But it's written in official documentation. Why is that?

Could you add more details please? In which scenarios is your CI running? Also having an excerpt of your CI file would be great. It's quite likely that the variable does not exist if your CI is not running on a MR or your GitLab version is older than 11.9

Can you give us an [mre] of your setup?

We're using GitLab Enterprise Edition 17.2.0. We're using our own ubuntu machine as a runner. It's is a classical terraform CI with 2 stages: terraform plan and terraform apply. Base image is alpine:3.19.1. I see all other env variables but not the CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE when I print env in the script.

This may seem like an obvious question, but is the job/pipeline triggered by a MR rather than just a commit?
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html

This issue might be related to what you're looking for https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/424864

@Arty-chan pipeline is triggered by a commit. My goal is not running pipeline if CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE contains "draft"

@Arty-chan yes, thats related issue. will follow it, thanks.
